# XenApp Console - Lost Administrator Password

Tags: password, citrix, console

Running MF 4.5 using XenApp Advanced Config Console.
I am administrator on the system but not configured for the console.
Is there any way to gain access to the console as the previous Citrix 
Admin has now left?
I would normally make the user/myself an administrator on MF using the 
Citrix Console but I can't get access.
Any pointers?
I have access to the datastore.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried this myself but have read of others who have had success with it. Hope it helps.
[Slim Jim](http://www.warmetal.nl/citrixlostadmin)

"If you've lost your Citrix Administrator Account you can't access the Citrix Management Console, which means you can't change anything in your Citrix farm. Citrix should prevent you from deleting the last administrator account, but that doesn't work if this is an Active Directory object. In this case you should delete all the local metaframe administrators so the local admin automatically gets the full administrative privileges in the farm. Slim Jim is an official but unsupported Citrix utility which does just that. Follow the steps outlined in this article to recover administrative access to your citrix farm. 
At the end of the article there are some links for extra additional information. "

Comment: Thank you very much for the heads up on Slim Jim. I have not heard of it before. As the article says - backup your DS before running. So I will need to tread carefully here. I will let you know how I get on